# Date minus 10 minutes in loop in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I have a loop that start from today to a old date, decremente date to 10 minutes each loop

the code have issue only in my symfony 2.8 ...
i rewrite the code without symfony for testing , and it work ...

```php
<?php
$start = new DateTime('2017-01-21T02:20:00+01:00');
$current = new DateTime('2019-01-01T02:20:00+01:00');

function dateIntervalToSeconds(\DateInterval $dateInterval)
{
    $reference = new \DateTimeImmutable;
    $endTime = $reference->add($dateInterval);

    return $endTime->getTimestamp() - $reference->getTimestamp();
}

function subDateIntervalToDatetime(\DateTime $dateTime, DateInterval $dateInterval)
{
    $newTimestamp = $dateTime->getTimestamp() - dateIntervalToSeconds($dateInterval);
    // return new \DateTime("@$newTimestamp", $dateTime->getTimezone()); <= timezone isn't set properly ...
    $newDate = new \DateTime("@$newTimestamp");
    $newDate->setTimezone($dateTime->getTimezone());
    return $newDate;
}

$i = 0;
while($current->getTimestamp() > $start->getTimestamp()) {
    echo $i . ' '. $current->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' -> ' . $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\r\n";
    $current = subDateIntervalToDatetime($current, new \DateInterval('PT10M'));
    $i++;
}
```

But in my symfony context the subDateIntervalToDatetime function say :2018-10-28 02:00:00 minus 10 minutes is 2018-10-28 02:50:00

the script have this error only on this date ...

i add this code in the function :

```php
        echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' -> ' . $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\r\n";
        if ($dateTime  < $newDate) {
            die;
        }
```

but never enter in the if ...

i juste replace the echo by this echo

```php
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . $dateTime->getTimestamp() .' -> ' . $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . $newDate->getTimestamp() . "\r\n";
```

and now i go throught the if ... but i alway have the main issue ...

Can you explain why ? and how to fix it ?
( why this date specialy ?)

PS: look the fun in video https://streamable.com/3vkxn

Edit, the function from my symfony project:

```php
protected function findMissingIntervals(ProbeData $probeData, $nbMissingValue, DateTime $dateStart, DateTime $dateEnd)
    {
        /** @var ProbeDataValueRepository $probeDataValueRepository */
        $probeDataValueRepository = $this->em->getRepository(ProbeDataValue::class);

        /** @var ProbeDataValue[} $data */
        $data = $probeDataValueRepository->findDataByProbeDataIndexedByDate($probeData, 'DESC');
        $currentDate = clone($dateEnd);

        $currentError = 0;
        $globalError = [];
        $tempErrorRange = null;
        while ($currentDate->getTimestamp() > $dateStart->getTimestamp() || $currentError < $nbMissingValue) {
            $exist = array_key_exists($currentDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $data);
            // inc count current Error
            if (!$exist) {
                $currentError++;
                if ($tempErrorRange === null) {
                    $tempErrorRange = [
                        'end' => clone($currentDate),
                    ];
                }
            } else {
                if ($tempErrorRange !== null) {
                    $tmpDate = clone($currentDate);
                    $tempErrorRange['start'] = $tmpDate->add(new \DateInterval('PT10M'));
                    $globalError[] = $tempErrorRange;
                    $tempErrorRange = null;
                }
            }

            // $currentDate = StaticHelper::subDateIntervalToDatetime($currentDate, new \DateInterval('PT10M'));
            $currentDate = $currentDate->sub(new \DateInterval('PT10M'));
            dump($currentDate->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        }

        $this->displayErrorIntervals($globalError);

        return $globalError;
    }
```

Comment: why you don't just use `$dateTime->sub($dateInterval)`?

Comment: timezones will always get you when it goes around the end of summer time and other weird stuff. Robert is right with their comment and answer. just use the proper functions intended for this.

Comment: @Robert , in fact i make this methods for fixing a bug like this ...

Comment: @Jakumi 28 ecotober 2018 is a DST day ...

Answer (score 2):

I think you did too much unnecessary logic. For me, it's just about using DateTime properly with a subtraction of interval

```
<?php

$start = new DateTime('2017-01-21T02:20:00+01:00');
$current = new DateTime('2019-01-01T02:20:00+01:00');
$tenMinInterval = new \DateInterval('PT10M');


for($i = 0; $current > $start; ++$i) {
   echo $i . ' '. $current->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' -> ' . $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\r\n";  
   $current->sub($tenMinInterval);
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 2019-01-01 02:20:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
1 2019-01-01 02:10:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
2 2019-01-01 02:00:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
3 2019-01-01 01:50:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
4 2019-01-01 01:40:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
5 2019-01-01 01:30:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
6 2019-01-01 01:20:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
7 2019-01-01 01:10:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
8 2019-01-01 01:00:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
9 2019-01-01 00:50:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
10 2019-01-01 00:40:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
11 2019-01-01 00:30:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
12 2019-01-01 00:20:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
13 2019-01-01 00:10:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
14 2019-01-01 00:00:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
15 2018-12-31 23:50:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
16 2018-12-31 23:40:00 -> 2017-01-21 02:20:00
```

About your case, you're playing with timezones and timestamps, when you convert DateTime to timestamp you lose information about the timezone. If you want to include timezones then set them in $start, $current DateTime constructor and if you want to convert it to a different one then use setTimezone() on DateTime.

Comment: Like i say my code work if i'm not in symfony ...
I shortcut my subDateIntervalToDatetime function with this two line `$temp = clone($dateTime);
        return $temp->sub($dateInterval);`

but when i start my code , i have the same issues ... 
my code loop between 2018-10-28 02:00:00 and 2018-10-28 02:50:00

Comment: It has nothing to do with Symfony, this code at least. Check your php settings and look for `date.timezone` instead and you can always specify timezone with `new DateTime('2018-10-28 02:00:00', new DateTimeZone('utc'))`

Comment: So i juste shortcut my code with datetime->sub(), doens't touche the timezone anymore ... still have same issue :/

Comment: I think i understand now ... 28/10/2018 is a dst day ...
so 2018-10-28 02:00:00 === 2018-10-28 03:00:00 in theory ...
And when i do 2018-10-28 02:00:00 minus 10 minutes, php do 2018-10-28 03:00:00 minus 10 minutes ...

This is why i try to use timestamp for fixing this issues ...
so timestamp doens't have the timezone ... and its alway utc ...

getting two timestamp , and reaplie the timezone should work but no!

Comment: just use the piece of code and you'll be sure your datetime is in utc and you can use methods and oop instead of old fashioned timestamp calculations